# What is the use of WebAPI checkbox in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am trying to create an ASP.NET MVC web application,I'm trying to understand what is the use of the check mark "WebAPI" ,I don't seem to find any different selecting or unselecting this while creating the project,can anyone throw some light?

[image]

Comment: It just includes all the references (.dll files) to allow you to create a web-api project as well

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET Web API** is a **framework** that makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building RESTful applications on the .NET Framework. Web API: Guidance.
You can take knowledge from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjwfcOKC_nQ) video. Thanks

Comment: OP is asking what the checkbox if for :)

Comment: Copy paste of text from the [Microsoft website](https://www.asp.net/web-api) is hardly an answer.